# How to create a column in a data frame that shows the days of the week from existing date column?

Tags: r, date

I have a date column and would like to create a new column by using mutate that shows the days of the week.

For example,

```
Date                  New Column      
2011-1-1                Wed
2012-1-3                Fri
```

I have about 1000 rows.

This is what I've tried

```
d <- mutate(d, days = days(Date, label=FALSE)
```

because, `d <- mutate(d, month = month(Date, label=False)` worked for me. I would assume it would be similar but I can't make it work.

Comment: you have to use `weekdays` function, `mutate(d, days = weekdays(Date))`

Answer (score 1):

Convert into date column and then use `weekdays`.

```
df$Date <- as.Date(df$Date, "%Y-%m-%d")
df$day_of_week <- weekdays(df$Date)
```

If you need abbreviated week days we can use `format`

```
df$short_day_of_week <- format(as.Date(df$Date, "%Y-%m-%d"), "%a")
df

#        Date day_of_week short_day_of_week
#1 2011-01-01    Saturday               Sat
#2 2012-01-03     Tuesday               Tue
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(Date = structure(1:2, .Label = c("2011-1-1", "2012-1-3"
), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-2L))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `wday` function from `lubridate` package

```r
df <- data.frame(Date = c("2011-1-1","2012-1-3"))

library(lubridate)
df %>% mutate(New_Column = wday(ymd(Date), label = TRUE))

      Date New_Column
1 2011-1-1        Sat
2 2012-1-3        Tue
```